# Equivalence Relation of Dice

Tags: combinatorics, equivalence-relations, dice

> Suppose you are rolling two dice, one red and one white. Two rolls of the dice are
>   considered equivalent if the dice sum to the same number. The dice are six-sided.
>
> a) Give the partition induced by this equivalence relation.
>
> b) How many equivalence relations exist on this set with the same size parts as the partition in part (a)?

Workings:

a. The partition would be numbers $1-6$ died on the red die and the numbers $1-6$ rolled on the white die.

b. There would be $36$ equivalence relations.

Roll a $1$ multiplied by the $6$ options on the other die to get $6$ multiply by $6$ again for the $6$ options on the original die.

I'm not sure if this is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to a) is wrong.

The question says "Two rolls of the dice are considered equivalent if the dice sum to the same number." The possible *sums* of the two dice range from $2$ through $12$. So one partition is all the possible rolls that sum to $2$, another with the sum $3$, and so on. This gives partitions of size $1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1$, as you note in your comment to this answer.

Now for part b). You need to find, out of a set of $36$, how many ways to get two sets of size $1$, two of size $2$, ..., two of size $5$, and one of size $6$. One way to do this is:

1) Find how many ways to choose $1$ from $36$, then $1$ from $35$. Multiply those two numbers, since they are independent, then divide by $2$ since you could have chosen either set first. (Note that the *numbers* here are independent, even though the choices themselves are not. You still multiple the numbers of choices.)

2) Find how many ways to choose $2$ from $34$, then $2$ from $32$. Multiply those two numbers, since they are independent, then divide by $2$ since you could have chosen either set first.

3-5) Do the same for choosing $3$, $4$, and $5$ from the numbers that are left.

6) You have only one choice to choose a set of $6$ from the remaining $6$ choices.

Then multiply those $6$ numbers together, since they are independent. There is no need to divide by anything, since sets of a given size are distinguishable from the other sets and cannot be interchanged.

Comment: So there would be 11 partitions.

b. The equivalence relations would be

For sum of $2: 1+1 [1] $


For sum of $3: 1+2, 2+1 [2]$ 

" $4: 1+3, 2+2, 3+1 [3]$ 

" $5: 1+4, 2+3, 3+2, 4+1 [4]$ 

" $6: 1+5, 2+4, 3+3, 4+2, 5+1 [5]$ 

" $7: 1+6, 2+5, 3+4, 4+3, 5+2, 6+1 [6]$
 
" $8: 2+6, 3+5, 4+4, 5+3, 6+2 [5]$
 
" $9: 3+6, 4+5, 5+4, 6+3 [4]$ 

" $10 4+6, 5+5, 6+4 [3]$
 
" $11: 5+6, 6+5 [2]$
 

" $12: 6+6 [1]$

Comment: @hockeynl: That seems to be correct (except for the typo "104"). See my edited answer for help in part b).